# iPhone App Rejected, Reason: App name to be displayed on the App Store does not sufficiently match the name of the app displayed on a device

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

My iPhone App Rejected. Here is Apple message from resolution center:

> We found that the app name to be displayed on the App Store does not
>   sufficiently match the name of the app displayed on a device, which is
>   not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> The Application Names are:
>
> Name on the App Store: Angry Stickman Ninja Run Pro Name displayed on
>   the device: Angry..un Pro

```
It would be appropriate to change one or both names so they are more similar. And remember, it is not appropriate to use keywords in your app name; please use these words as search terms for your app by entering them in the Keywords field in iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications.
```

Here both are same, but by default iPhone names on device is trimmed.

**1. Is there any character limit in product name? If so then how much character allowed?**

Comment: @MarcusAdams, I set 'Angry Stickman' and got truncated...so I thought its not allowed again

Comment: Angry Birds, Fruit Ninja, Temple Run, DragonVale, Dragon Story, etc -- An app name made up of an amalgamation of the names of all the top selling games and you seriously can't figure out why Apple has a problem with that?

Comment: try product name size less than 13.

Comment: @aepryus, yup you are right..its not valid name, but message from apple resolution center is not straight forward..right?

Comment: Try "Angry Stick" (tested).

Comment: Wow, that name is even worse than [Super Monster Bros by Adventure Time Pocket Free](http://www.ign.com/videos/2013/04/24/iphone-garbage-super-monster-bros-by-adventure-time-pocket-free-games)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the device, I *think* it's a fixed width, not a number of characters (since some characters are wider than others).  It usually is about 7-10 chars though.

I'd go with either "Ninja Run" or "Stickman"

Comment: thanks for the reply, second time I used iDragonPro, apple rejected with reason not same. see update section in question.

Comment: right, but iDragonPro isn't really at all like the App Store long name  of "Angry Stickman Ninja Run of Dragon Temple Pro"

Comment: ok let me set "Ninja Run" this time and lets see what happens..

Comment: Might try AngryStickman (without the space, too)

Comment: @MikeM, even without the space, AngryStickman is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

I published a app to the app store about 6 months ago as a test. It was a Pascal Cased name and it was 16 characters so on the device it did end up with ... in the name.

It looks like it is more to do with relevance unless they have changed their policy.

Comment: After may-1st apple set many new rules.